# Return Dictionary<int,List<Int>> from EntityFramework table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dictionary

I need to select `Dictionary<Int32, List<Int32>>` from `EntityFramework` table.
I am using below query but unable to make it work to result as `Dictionary`.

```
 var result= _dbNavigation.BudgetRevenueMileStones
                          .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.BRMTaskTemplateID.Value
                                            , value => value.BRMTaskID.Value );
```

The table structure is like below.

```
ID  BRMTaskID   BRMTaskTemplateID
708 309880       6268   
709 309893       6268   
710 309925       6268   
711 301111       6255
```

Expected output is(as `Dictionary<Int,List<Int>>`)

```
6268, 309880,309893,309925
6255, 301111
```

Comment: You need to group the data. Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group your records based on `BRMTaskTemplateID`

```
var result= _dbNavigation.BudgetRevenueMileStones 
             .GroupBy(x => x.BRMTaskTemplateID)
             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                           g => g.Select(x => x.BRMTaskID).ToList());
```